# auto repeat data in mysql for ten times

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible for data to be inputted in one column of a mysql and then be repeated for the next 10 entries of data inputted into mysql?

I am asking this as I'm trying to create a system where a user chooses data from 10 options but next time they attempt to choose data, they are prompted not to select the same data for the next 10 choices.

Thanks,

Chris

Here an example of the data using 3 options. For this example when the option is selected it inserts 'Y' and on the next row when data is received it automatically sets another 'Y' within that option.

```
Entry Option 1 Option 2 Option 3
    1 Y        N        N
    2 Y        Y        N
    3 N        Y        Y
    4                   Y
```

Comment: Let's pretend its '3' instead of '10'. Now, can you construct a sample data set that better illustrates the problem?

Comment: I've updated my original post with a basic html table displaying the data with 3 options. In row 4 the user will select either option 1 or 2. When it comes to selecting data for entry 5, the selected data from entry 4 will automatically be set to a Y. Can this be programmed to be done in MySQL?

Comment: I think you should do this type of behavior on the application level and not on database.